# Linux disk expansion error:You must delete some partition and add an extended partition first

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, diskmanagement

I researched the reasons for this error,
Can't do more than 4 parts There must be a way to increase disk space
disk I want to increase the system virtual linux centos 6 
I'm connecting with ssh-putty

How can I help you please.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

an mbr style partition table can handle 4 partition, not more. If you want more partition, you have to do what fdisk tells you. Create an extended partition (for that you will have to delete one, preferably the last one), then you can create more logical partitions inside the extended partition.

Alternatively, you can convert the partition table to GPT, which supports more than 4 partitions. This can however break your system completely. Always make a backup first.

Since this is a virtual system, other options are:

- Increase the existing partition to use the rest of the space
- Instead of increasing the size of the current disk, add an additional virtual disk and add that new disk to your LVM.